# Printing an 2d array with no extra white space or line

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, newline, whitespace

I am trying to write a method for a 2D array that will print our my values with a single space in between them and the rows will have a single new line character between them. There should also be no space before the first value or after the last vale or a newline before the first or after the last row. My values print out neatly, but I don't know how to make sure that there are no extra lines or spaces. I was thinking of implementing an if statement into my code or using the trim method. Here is my code!

```
public static String arrayToString(int a[][]){

    int row = a.length;
    int column = a[0].length;
    String array = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j< column; j++){
            array += a[i][j] + " ";

        }
        array += "/n";
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `if` statements that will check if it is end of line or end of everything and based on that add or not add space or new line.

So instead of just having this `array += a[i][j] + " ";`

You need to check `if (i != row - 1)` (which is the end of the line) and only in such case add space.

The same applies for the `array += "/n";`, you need to check the value of `j` to make sure you not add it when you are at the end

Answer (score 0):

You just answered your own question

Trim the last char

```
public static String arrayToString(float a[][]){

        int row = a.length;
        int column = a[0].length;
        String array = ""; // I removed the space you had here
        for (int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j< column; j++){
                array += a[i][j] + " ";

            }
            array += "\n"; // I changed /n to \n
        }

        return array.substring(0,array.length()-2); // return the trimmed string
    }
```

or add if statements to check if it is the last item

```
public static String arrayToString(float a[][]){

        int row = a.length;
        int column = a[0].length;
        String array = ""; // I removed the space you had here
        boolean isLast = false;
        for (int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j< column; j++){
                isLast = i == row-1 && j == column-1;
                if(isLast)
                    array += a[i][j];
                else
                    array += a[i][j] + " ";

            }
            if(!isLast)
                array += "\n"; // I changed /n to \n
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized right after I said it out loud